# JSOM Break SharePoint List Item Permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom, ajax, role-assignment

I wrote the following code to break list item permission. Code works fine other than a small issue.

```
var user;
function breakItemPermission(itemID) {
    //Get the current context  
    var context = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemID);
    oListItem.breakRoleInheritance(false);
    getCurrentUser();
    console.log(user);//undefined always
    var oUser = context.get_web().ensureUser(user);
    oListItem.get_roleAssignments().getByPrincipal(oUser).deleteObject();
    context.load(oUser);
    Id = itemID;
    context.load(oListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    console.log('Role inheritance broken for item ');
    grantPermission(Id);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    grantPermission(Id);
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
function getCurrentUser(){
    var context = new SP.ClientContext();
    currentUser = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    context.load(currentUser);
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceededGetCurrentUser), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailedGetCurrentUser));
}

function onQuerySucceededGetCurrentUser() { 
    user=currentUser.get_email();
}

function onQueryFailedGetCurrentUser(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

In breakItemPermission() function user variable is always undefined even it's defined as global. Due to that current user permission cannot be broken. 
Any hack to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your function `getCurrentUser()` has an async operation (`executeQueryAsync`). JS does not wait for it to complete and executes the next line i.e. `console.log(user)`.

You need write the subsequent code from `getCurrentUser()` inside the function `onQuerySucceededGetCurrentUser` then only you will get the current user.